# Getting image from Rest API. JQuery issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Two related questions.

```
(this is my jquery.js file)

$.ajax
    ({
     type: "GET",
     url: "url",
     dataType: 'image/png',
     async: false,

     beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     xhr.withCredentials = true;
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxxx");
     },

     success: function (data) {

     document.getElementById("myImage").src = data; // (will be in next question)
     console.log(data);
     }

     });
```

When I get JSON data, it will put that data into the chrome console (developer tools) via the console.log. However with the png I don't see any data. This worries me because in the request response for the picture I see the binary data

```
�Ս-��tKn�v���6�k�˟>��������7�&=���+���?J�k�����y����L���m�(ψ/
```

but I need to make sure this is in the data variable because of the .src = data line.

This leads into my next question.... If the image binary data is in the "data" variable, shouldnt it be displayed in my html?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="myImage" src="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that ajax call at all? just set

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = url;
```

even if you do get contents of the image via the ajax call, get around all browser issues, encoding issues etc., you can't just display that image, becuase the "src" attribute of an img take a URL not a data stream.

Beside that, you code seems fine, if I go to JQuery.com and run this in the console (FireFox - latest), I will get the datastream:

```
$.ajax
    ({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery.com/i/feature-sprites.png",
     dataType: 'image/png',
     async: false,

     success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
     }

     });
```

You may want to ensure your authentication is not failing, and since you are probably running the script on a domain that is different from that of the API you should ensure the API allows CORS (Cross Origin Resouce Sharing) which basically means you can call it from a different domain.

Comment: I was under the impression I needed the ajax call because its a link that required authorization (the bearer token)

Comment: Unless you can save the stream somewhere and then set the URL of the <img /> to that location, you won't be able to do much with the data. Since this is a get request, you may have the option of passing your authentication token  in an alternative way, say through a URL parameter.

Your other option would be to make this request server side, in which case you will set the src attribute to the end point on your server, and there you make a request to the target api with the proper authorization header, and then stream the response back to you client - again that is if you run server side code.

Comment: thanks for the comment hnafar, that makes sense. my concern is the binary data response from the request isnt being stored in the "data" variable, is that right? or is it actually being stored there, and its just not being printed with console.log

Comment: Thanks for editing it definitely works. It had been giving me the 403 cors error for a while, but now I set up a https on localhost it works fine. Just need to get the image data it returns into that html tag. I'll keep goin at it and let you know. Thanks!